# Can the Loki version of Epiphany browser be installed in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, release-loki, epiphany, internet-browser

I find the default Loki browser Epiphany to be an excellent choice in many respects, and surely not just by comparison to Midori; it is light (given RAM is cheap), fast and stable, and I can see it as a good choice beside the big ones like Firefox and Chrome/Chromium.

I have installed Epiphany (Web) in Freya but it does not have the 'elementary' design it has in Loki. Nor the same smoothness ( -- but then again, this can be subjective rant...).

Is it the same version/package?

Is the Loki version available in Freya?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not because epiphany in Loki uses gtk3.18. Freya uses 3.14. I've run into that issue with a couple of other programs.

Answer (score 1):

No. I am not running either at the moment (And I usually run the latest packages from the daily PPA on top of the latest available Ubuntu version), but I can pretty much assure you they are different versions of the same browser.

Epiphany is being actively developed by the Gnome developers and thus you will find that there are many differences between the version in Freya (which IIRC is 3.14 or 3.16) and Loki, (which is most likely 3.20).

Your best bet is to simply wait on Loki :)